# How I can add data to firebase firestore on server-side

Tags: firebase, server-side, serverside-javascript

At the moment I am working with a payment system. After successful payment, the system sends a POST request to my domain with all data about its payment. I should to process this request and add the user's amount to his balance.

My DB is firebase. How I can do this on the server-side.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Firebase Admin SDK with the language of your choice.